# PHP Search query with Insert Statement

Tags: php, mysql, full-text-search

I am working on a product search in PHP/MySQL. When a User search for a Product (Can search for more than one product, its a dropdown with multiselect), it should take the data from Table A and Inserts in Table B. The user can search for more than one product. I have problem in query. It is slow, and it is not getting all the products related to product search. sometimes its just taking the first search criteria.

The query iam using is as follows:

```
$arr = explode(",",$values["prod_cat"]);

for ($i=0;$i<count($arr);$i++)
{
  $strSQLInsert = "INSERT INTO TABLE B (sup_id, sup_name, sup_product, sup_contactperson, 
                   sup_contactperson_email, tender_id) 

                   (SELECT sup_id, sup_name, sup_prod_name, sup_contactperson, sup_email, 
                   ".$values["tender_id"]." FROM TABLE A WHERE sup_prod_name IN 
                   ('".$arr[$i]."')  GROUP BY sup_name)";
```

Am i making any mistake?

Comment: There a particular reason to insert in Table B products from Table A? You will use Table B for what?

Comment: If you want Table B as temporary then you can use 'view'. It will better for your execution of code.

Comment: @Fusion. That is actually a client requirement. First he will search for products. The result (Product name)should be saved to another tableB

Comment: @WisdmLabs. Its not a temp table.. It should be saved in the actual table..

Comment: Maybe try SELECT INTO statement. Select from Table A into Table B where sub_prod_name.  Why you need to GROUP BY when you are just inserting into another table? Maybe that might cause a delay?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You explode `$values['prod_cat']` in `$arr`, then iterate it performing multiple queries with a `IN` condition for each `$arr` value.

`IN` clausole exists for multiple values (for single value simply use `WHERE sup_prod_name = ''`), so you can avoid `for()` loop and perform only one query transforming `$values['prod_cat']` in this way:

```
$prod_cat_names = "'" . str_replace( ",", "','", $values["prod_cat"] ) . "'";
/*
    Example:    cat1,cat2,cat3    =>    'cat1','cat2','cat3'
*/
```

and using this query **without `for()` loop**:

```
"
INSERT INTO TABLE B 
            (sup_id, sup_name, sup_product, sup_contactperson, sup_contactperson_email, tender_id) 

            (
            SELECT sup_id, sup_name, sup_prod_name, sup_contactperson, sup_email, ".$values["tender_id"]." 
              FROM TABLE A 
             WHERE sup_prod_name IN ( {$prod_cat_names} )
             GROUP BY sup_name
            )
"
```

Also, I don't know your exact table structure, but if in Table A `sup_id` is the unique id of `sup_name`, consider possibility of replace `GROUP BY sup_name` with `GROUP BY sup_id`.

With this code your insert statement will result faster.

---

About retrieving rows from query, you say: “it is not getting all the products related to product search”: I don't know what do you use, because in my experience `INSERT` statement returns **no rows**.

If you want perform a select->insert->retrieve with best performance available, you have to use a [stored procedure call](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-net/en/connector-net-tutorials-stored-procedures.html), otherwise you have to perform two queries, one for the `SELECT`, one for the `INSERT`:

```
/* Select Query as SELECT from previous example: */
$selectQuery = 
"
    SELECT sup_id, sup_name, sup_prod_name, sup_contactperson, sup_email, ".$values["tender_id"]." 
      FROM TABLE A 
     WHERE sup_prod_name IN ( {$prod_cat_names} )
     GROUP BY sup_name
";

/* Perform the query: */
$result = $db->query( $selectQuery );
$result->setFetchMode( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );

$insertQuery = array();

/* Process result and pre-fill Insert Query: */
while( $row = $result->fetch() )
{
    /*
        Put here your code to echo / process returned row...
    */

    $insertQuery[] = "'" . implode( "', '",$row ) . "'";
}

/* Format INSERT Query: */
$insertQuery =
"
INSERT INTO TABLE B 
            (sup_id, sup_name, sup_product, sup_contactperson, sup_contactperson_email, tender_id) 
            VALUES
            ("
            . implode( "), (", $insertQuery ) . 
            ")
";

/* Permorm INSERT Query: */
$db->query( $insertQuery );
```

**Please carefully note:** above code is for example purpose only: with this code, all values as casted as text string, so you have to check if your real fields values in TABLE B are compatibles with text insert: otherwise, you have to check each field value building query string.

I have used `PDO` as MySQL driver. You can replace PDO commands with your preferred driver commands.

Comment: Thank you so much. Let me try to execute this. Really appreciate it.

Comment: Iam trying to do the query with seperate select and Insert Statement. Iam getting some errors when i try to do that. The error is " Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '") ' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING) in D:\xampp\htdocs\crm\include\rfq_events.php on line 298". Some mistake in the implode function of the insert Statement. Iam trying to solve it

Comment: i guess the problem with single quotes or double quote used

Comment: What are in line 298?

Comment: The following is there in line no 298....("
            . implode( "), (", $insertQuery )
            ")

Comment: @SanjuMenon You are right. There is a typo in my example. The correct form is `INSERT INTO TABLEB () VALUES ()`. Now the answer is correct. BTW, do an echo of `$insertQuery` after creating it to see if it is correct. The right form is: `INSERT INTO TABLE ( field1, field2, etc ) VALUES ( 'val1', 'val2', etc ), ( 'val1.1', 'val2.1', etc ), ( ... )`

Comment: There is still some problem with quotations i guess. i gave an echo and its showing like this. INSERT INTO Table B (sup_id, sup_name, sup_product, sup_contactperson, sup_contactperson_email, tender_id) VALUES ( . implode( ), (, Array ) )

Comment: Yup, definitely there is it a quotation issue. It seems you forgot quotes before and after `implode()`  ... and I forgot a dot after `$insertQuery` ! > `"INSERT INTO TABLE B ( ... ) VALUES (" . implode( "), (", $insertQuery ) . ")";`

Comment: Thanx a lot, its solved it. The sup_name is repeating. so is it wise to use GROUP BY sup_name? Or will it slow down the search?

Comment: I don't think. Try and see. But you don't already `GROUP BY sup_name`  ?

Comment: yes i was using it, then i removed it.. i will implement it again and see if its slow down. Thanx a lot. Really appreciate your help.

Comment: There is a small issue, If the search cant find any product, its showing an error. INSERT INTO Table B (sup_id, sup_name, sup_product, sup_contactperson, sup_contactperson_email, tender_id) VALUES () ; .......Column count doesn't match value count at row 1

Comment: I think that it is, but I don't know it. Try to ask for a specific question, or search on google. The `IF` operator exists in mysql, so i guess that you can find something.

Answer (score 0):

for searching i will suggest you to use Pdo or object oriented Mysql rather than raw query. Apart from that you can simply use

```
"Select field_name1, field_name2 from table A where field_name like '%text%'";
```

once you get the loop than insert into your table b

```
"Insert into field_name1, field_name2 values(field_name1, field_name2);
```

Comment: In this case how will i store it in array?

Comment: Also the user can search more than one product. The user can select product from a drop down with multiselect...